# Fixed length, 6-bit binary string in perl

Tags: perl, binary, decimal

Is it possible to print a fixed length binary string in perl of binary characters?
What I have so far, is this:

```
printf(OUTFILE "%b\n", $nextToken);
```

But this only prints out relevant bits. i.e. If $nextToken = 3, then the string only prints out:

11

What I want it to print out, is:

000011

Is there an easy way to get perl to print out the extra 4 characters to make this a 6-character long binary string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).  The very first example shows how to add leading 0's

```
printf(OUTFILE "%06b\n", $nextToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `"%06b"` is what you want.

Looking at the [`sprintf` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), you can see that the `0` means "use zeros, not spaces, to right-justify", and the `6` is the minimum width to be printed.